# after returning back from my second Activity to first Activity on clicking button the whole data is gone

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have two activties:
activity_main,
activity_display

in the main_activity user enters his/her name and presses the toggle button to display.
that takes the user to display_activity page where the result is displayed.
if the user finds that he/she has entered the wrong info they can go back and edit.

here is where the problem starts
after pressing the toggle button - display
it goes to display_activity and displays but when I press "back" button I'm restarting the whole (first) main_activity again... no values are present...
even the toggle button that needs to be set to "reset" is again showing "display".

should i use something else instead of

```
                        startActivity(intend1);
```

i want to resume the (first) activity main not restart everything

Comment: If you just started to work on a new project, then use fragments instead of activity.

Comment: @maddy23285 There's a lot of reasons not to use Fragments, they have issues in a lot of ways.  Many organizations  ban them outright in their code.

Comment: Are you implementing onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState in your first activity?  Those are your hooks to make sure state is remembered even if the activity restarts

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your first activity uses results from second activity. you can use startActivityForResult. Here is a very good answer refer to it.

[How to manage startActivityForResult on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)